# Bluetooth in Android SDK 1.6

Tags: android

How do I turn Bluetooth on/off in Android SDK 1.6?

Comment: Plz...provide some more details. No one will understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to enable/disable bluetooth from your code? That could be a security risk for the user and limit battery life.

Comment: James Black yes. I need a code.

Comment: If I recall correctly that isn't possible pre Android 2.0 But I'm not a 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling and disabling Bluetooth is done through `Settings.Secure` and therefore is not available to ordinary SDK applications.